# How to get OWinContext from HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-identity, owin

Recently we replaced the old Membership to ASP.NET Identity in MVC.
Went according to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762428/ASP-NET-MVC-and-Identity-Understanding-the-Basics 
Trying to get a hold of the "ApplicationUserManager" instance in :

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<IdentityUserManager>( ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    UserManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager< ApplicationUserManager >();
}
```

Which is being called from Startup.cs 
However, I receive an exception:

```
 "No owin.Environment item was found in the context".
```

I Added all the parameters to config file as mentioned in other posts

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="[namespace]Startup, [namespace]" />
```

Above Startup namespace:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof([namespace].Startup))]
```

Any other suggestions?